# OpenVPN unable to access Internet

Tags: routes, vpn, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server installed on my RaspberryPi and an Arch(Manjaro) laptop as personal device. At home everything works quite well and I am able to access the Internet through the tunnel. When I am connected to a foreign (open) wifi I cannot access the internet any more though I am still able to connect to the OpenVPN server. On my Android device it also works fine through mobile network, but when using the same foreign wifi there is no possibility anymore to access the internet (still connected to the server). I assume it has somethink to do with the routing, but I am not sure. But I noticed that the 'link' at the 'tun0' device is set to 'none'. It would be great if anybody could help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have LZO compression (comp-lzo) specified in your client configuration but not the server configuration